# why we can find domain of a function by taking intersection of domains of individual functions but not range

Tags: functions, inverse

why we can find domain of a function by taking intersection of domains of individual functions  but not range by taking intersection of ranges of individual function.
for example- for finding range of f(x) = cos^(-1)x + cot^(-1)x
we will domain by intersection of domains of cos inverse and cot inverse
and then find range by putting them into equation to find maxima and minima? why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can you clarify what *why we can find the domain of a function by taking the intersection of domains of individual functions* means? At least by providing an example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that $\arccos x$ has a range of $[0, \pi]$, and $\text{arccot } x$ also has a range of $[0, \pi]$, but the range of $\arccos x + \text{arccot } x$ is not $[0, 2 \pi]$ as you have mentioned.

This is because there is no value of $x$ such that $\arccos x = 0$ *and* $\text{arccot } x = 0$. However, if you have $f(x) + g(x)$ and $f(x)$ is not defined at $x = 0$, $f(x) + g(x)$ is not defined unless the term with the discontinuity at $x = 0$ disappears completely ($\frac{1}{x}, \ln x$ etc.) For example, take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}, g(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$.